# Azure Mobile Service Custom Authentication - Logging Out

Tags: c#, authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm implementing custom authentication in my mobile service using the [LoginProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobile.service.security.loginprovider.aspx) class found in the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security namespace.

After I login and create a LoginResult object, is it possible to "logout" that object such that the authentication token can no longer be used? Or is the only option to wait for the token to expire?